# How to invoke click on p:button automatically in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a p:button that opens a new tab, i want to invoke the click automatically on this button from another component in the same page

```html
<p:button id="newTab" value="Open" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" />
```

I have tried the JS click but i doesn't work (it works for p:commandButton)

```js
function openTab() {
    $('#form\\:newTab').click();
}
```

Does any one have an idea, thanks in advance !

Comment: Works fine for me.  Go to the showcase here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/button.xhtml and press F12 to bring up the JS Console.  Enter `$('#j_idt697').click();` and press ENTER. It clicks the Bookmark link.

Comment: Works for me too, but maybe your browser is preventing popups from javascript (which is good!).

Comment: Maybe You have some errors before runing this `openTab()` function. To make sure just use browser console (ctrl + shift + j in firefox) to see the errors.